# Summation of concated fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, math

In a database, I have fields for scoring users. They are as following:

```
id | user_id | month | week | activity | speed
```

So, I want to get **activity+speed** in one field, BUT from a GROUP_CONCAT results, as I have more than one scoring, for one user (different week & month).

My current query is as following:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT( CONVERT( tfts_bodovanja.activity + tfts_bodovanja.speed, 
      CHAR( 8 ) ) SEPARATOR  '+' ) AS indeks
FROM tfts_fans
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY indeks DESC
```

And it returns (for the bolded part):

```
191.4000+383.1999
```

And ordering doesn't work, obviously.

So, all I want is just to sum up those two numbers and mysql to return them as FLOAT. How is that achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT with a "+" will create a string and won't do an addition. Assuming you want the sum of (activity+speed) for each user you can do something like this

```
SELECT user_id,
       SUM( activity + speed ) AS indeks
FROM tfts_fans 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY indeks DESC
```

Comment: Yes, I want the addition, but of the "concated" fields (rows), not just the columns themselves...

Comment: @user533368 Not sure I understand your comment. My query sums the values in the columns (i.e. the row values) and not the columns. Maybe post some example data and some example results if my query doesn't do what you want?

Comment: If I have rows like:
id | activity | speed;;;
1 | 12.3 | 33.2;;;
2 | 43.2 | 99.3;;;

I want to get result as SUM of ALL those above (to cut the story short, I have some distinction of selecting the rows in question). 

So, your query would return two rows with the indeks values of 45.5 and 142.5, and I need one row with sum of these two: 188.0...

Comment: @user533368 My query will return the results GROUPed by user_id which seems to be what your original question is asking for. Thus if those sample rows are for the same user_id it will return 188.0 for that user_id.